# Multiserver Spring Websockets Application Issue With Sessions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, activemq-classic

I have a java application with Spring messaging.
I use relay stomp (ActiveMQ) and also have set user registry broadcast and user destination topic as well.
It works as intended when I use on a single server. When I install the application on multiple servers and put behind a load balancer, issue starts to occur.
Upon digging deeper, I found out that user sessions are broadcasted fine every milliseconds across the servers but when an xhr_send (not using ws protocol but xhr-streaming) is received at a server, it does not check from the sessions that the server received from activemq, but only checks in local sessions. Since the session was created on another server it fails.
Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: that's exactly my issue, have you solved it?